# Moving a div to the right

Tags: javascript, css

I have this really fundamental question, but I have no idea wheres the problem.

Here's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nL6fvrz8/

I just simply want to move the object to the right with this js, but when I do that in the fiddle it doesnt move at all and if I do it on my computer, it keeps giving me the primary position of the 200px(the amount i want to add it to its first position)

```
function doMove(){
var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
foo.style.left = (foo.style.left + 200) + 'px';
}
```

I know its prolly a little simple, but im clueless. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Change onload to wrap in head in jsfiddle settings.

Comment: You need to call the function: `doMove();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only inline styles can be referenced via the `x.style` syntax. To get styles set via a style sheet, use `getComputedStyle`:

```
function doMove() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("foo");
    var foo = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("left");
    elem.style.left = parseInt(foo,10) + 200 + 'px';
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/nL6fvrz8/2/)**

Comment: No problem. If you feel that this answered your question, then consider checking it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Ill do that of course, actually your code is the noly one from all of the below that works. Could you please just tell me why I need to use two variables for this and why cant I use just parseInt?(if the reason of it is that its not an inline style i think get it)

Comment: Technically you don't have to use two variables, I just found it a bit easier to work with and more readable. And I'm not sure what you're asking for with regard to parseInt().

Comment: what i meant was that in this example http://www.schillmania.com/content/projects/javascript-animation-1/demo/
people use no .getComputedStyle and it works perfectly.

Comment: Because they're actually setting the inline style. If you look at the code, in the init() function they have `foo.style.left = '0px';` which sets the inline style. Remove that line and you'll see that it no longer works. And they also left the radix out of their parseInt() call.

Comment: ok, so basically I have two options, first is to use getComputedStyle and the second one is to set the .style.left which makes it the inline style. If I said it right, thanks for your explanation!

Comment: If you set the styles inline, then you can use the x.style syntax instead of getComputedStyle, but getComputedStyle will work on both inline styles and style sheet rules.

Answer (score 0):

Define basic position in JS as well, and add parseInt when reading style (left is string in format like this `200px`).

```js
document.getElementById("foo").style.left = "300px";
function doMove() {
    var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
    foo.style.left = (parseInt(foo.style.left) + 200) + 'px';
}
```